# Why does locals()['var_name'] = value affect the actual local namespace?

Tags: python, function, scope, namespaces, local

```
def f():
    s = 'foo'
    loc = locals()

    loc['s'] = 'bar'
    print(s)

    loc['z'] = 'baz'
    print(locals())

f()
```

I understand that the locals function returns a copy of the local namespace. That's why the value of s doesn't get modified in the actual local namespace. If that's the case, then why does an additional key-value pair to loc affect the actual local namespace?

Comment: Did you read the note [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) **The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter.** i.e. your reasoning is incorrect in the first place

Comment: It doesn't, try `print(z)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `__import__('dis').dis(lambda: z)`

Comment: @user3840170 what?